# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] python 3.4 post commit hook

Tags: python, windows, visualsvn-server

processCommit.py script looks like:

```
cmd = 'C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook changed %s -r %s' %   (repo, rev)
Line 15 -->**changed = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]**
cmd = 'C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook info %s -r %s' % (repo, rev)
```

Error that I am getting after commit :

```
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):  
Error:   File "D:\Repositories\IapAdmin\hooks\processCommit.py", line 15, in <module>  
Error:     changed = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]  
Error:   File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__  
Error:     restore_signals, start_new_session)  
Error:   File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child  
Error:     startupinfo)  
Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Python 3.5 is still just an alpha release; any reason you are using it over Python 3.4?

Comment: Looks like your `processCommit.py` file has parse errors. I'm pretty sure the error message is pointing right at your mistake. You may wish to follow a Python tutorial to learn more.

Comment: Now I am pointing to python 3.4

Comment: I am getting the following commit message but I am trying to figure out two thing **0700** and **57** what is the relation with the commit any idea?.............................................A commit has been made to the IAPAdmin repository
*** Commit Information ***
jambhus
2015-04-03 08:58:50 -0700 (Fri, 03 Apr 2015)
57
Adding new file App_new1.java and deleting file App3.java

*** Changed Files ****

D   trunk/Alpha/src/main/java/jar/App3.java
A   trunk/Alpha/src/main/java/jar/App_new1.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes around `swachand.jambhulkar@pers.state.or.us`:

```
session.sendmail('swachand.jambhulkar@pers.state.or.us', 'swachand.jambhulkar@pers.state.or.us', msg.as_string())
```

**Update**

```
cmd = 'C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook changed %s -r %s' % (repo, rev)
changed = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0] # line 15
cmd = 'C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook info %s -r %s' % (repo, rev)
```

Instead of using `\` for paths, use `/`:

```
cmd = 'C:/Program Files/VisualSVN Server/bin/svnlook changed %s -r %s' % (repo, rev)
```

Comment: Getting this error now     
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):  
Error:   File "D:\Repositories\IapAdmin\hooks\processCommit.py", line 15, in <module>  
Error:     changed = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]  
Error:   File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 855, in __init__  
Error:     restore_signals, start_new_session)  
Error:   File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 1123, in _execute_child  
Error:     startupinfo)  
Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Update the question with the code that is throwing that, at and around line 15.

Comment: cmd = 'C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook changed %s -r %s' % (repo, rev) ----line 14
changed = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0] ----line 15
cmd = 'C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook info %s -r %s' % (repo, rev)------line 16

Comment: It is working now, I am getting email on every commit...Thanks

Comment: I am getting the following commit message but I am trying to figure out two thing **0700** and **57** what is the relation with the commit any idea?.............................................A commit has been made to the IAPAdmin repository
*** Commit Information ***
jambhus
2015-04-03 08:58:50 -0700 (Fri, 03 Apr 2015)
57
Adding new file App_new1.java and deleting file App3.java

*** Changed Files ****

D   trunk/Alpha/src/main/java/jar/App3.java
A   trunk/Alpha/src/main/java/jar/App_new1.java